# Does Spring support SharePoint

Tags: java, sharepoint, spring

Does Spring support SharePoint?

In my Spring Application, i would like to SAVE data in ShaePoint.

In another (java) application of ours, we are using CAML to read/update the data in SharePoint.

Do you think I should use the same(CAML) or does Spring provides any APIs which makes my job easy.

Thank You :)

EDIT: Its SharePoint 2003 and WSS 2.0

Comment: Hey hanuathena, can you please help me out for this same issue. if possible than we can communicate on skype also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your Java application you should be able to send XML to the SharePoint webservices. Check this link for the WSS 3.0 web services SDK: [WSS 3.0 Webservices SDK (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms441339%28office.12%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK SharePoint **should** also support HTTP GET/POST for reading/writing data. However, in my own experience, reading/saving data from Java to SharePoint usually involves problem at the authentication level. In fact SharePoint usually uses NTLM authentication, which is hard to implement in Java. I did some experiments in the past using [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.0.1/index.html) and implementing NTML authentication as described [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.0.1/tutorial/html/authentication.html#ntlm), which requires [jCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/).

Another quicker, but dirtier, option is the following. Since SharePoint ultimately stores files on the file system, just expose that path as a [Windows UNC Path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Uniform_Naming_Convention), and make it available from the machine where your Java application runs. Then, Java can just open a `File` on the UNC Path in the usual way, and everything is transparent for you application (A UNC Path will look something like `\\machine-name\path\to\store`). This is not very elegant, and possibly not very secure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the download link for WSS 2.0 [WSS 2.0 SDK Download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=1c64af62-c2e9-4ca3-a2a0-7d4319980011&displaylang=en)